next.js code is not working, I am using zod, with react-hook-form
this is the code
'use client';
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import {z} from 'zod'
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";


const Schema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email('Email is not valid').min(1, 'Email is required'),
  password: z.string().min(4, 'Password must be at least 4 characters'),
  rememberMe: z.boolean().optional()
});
type LoginFields = z.infer<typeof Schema>;

export default function LoginPage() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState : {
      errors,
      isSubmitting
    }
  } = useForm<LoginFields>({
    resolver: zodResolver(Schema),
  })

  const router = useRouter()

  const onSubmit : SubmitHandler<LoginFields>= async (data) => {
    try{
      console.log(data)
      // add authentication login here
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,1000));
      //toast.success("login successfull")
      console.log(data.email, data.password)
      const res = await fetch('/api/userAuth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: data.email,
          password: data.password,
          rem: data.rememberMe
        })
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data.data)
        localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.data)
        toast.success(data.message);
        router.push('/company')
      } else {
        const errordata = await res.json();
        toast.warning(errordata.message)
      }
      // router.replace('/company');
    }catch(error){
      console.error('Login failed',error);
      toast.error("login failed")
    }

  };



  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row justify-between min-h-screen items-center  gap-24">
      {/* heading and images */}
      <div className=" relative bg-primary h-screen w-full flex justify-center items-center">
        <div className="animate-fade-in">
          <p className="text-white text-3xl">Login to work with us.</p>
          <div className="my-2 mx-5 text-center space-y-1 text-white">
            <p className="opacity-65">@</p>
            <p> Obscidian</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* login form */}
      <div className="pt-10  min-w-[25em] border-2 border-primary rounded-2xl animate-fade-in shadow-xl mr-[15%]">
        <div className="my-7 mx-5">
          <p className="text-3xl font-bold w-full text-center">Welcome! </p>
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="px-5 my-7">
          <div className="space-y-1">
            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
            <Input 
              id="email"
              {...register('email')}
              placeholder="Enter your email"
            />
            {errors.email && (<div className="text-red-500">{errors.email.message}</div>)}
          </div>
          <div className="space-y-1 mt-4">
            <Label htmlFor="password" >Password</Label>
            <Input 
              id="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              showPasswordToggle={true}
              {...register('password')}
            />
            {errors.password && (<div className="text-red-500">{errors.password.message}</div>)}
          </div>

          {/* remember me and forgot password */}
          <div className="flex  justify-between items-center my-3 text-sm font-semibold">
            <div className="flex items-end gap-2">
              <Checkbox id="remember"
                {...register('rememberMe')}/>
              <Label htmlFor="remember" >Remember me</Label>
            </div>
            <Link href="/user/forgot-password">Forgot password?</Link>
          </div>

          <Button 
            type="submit" 
            className="w-full text-white mt-6 hover:bg-primary-dark" 
            size="xl"
            disabled = {isSubmitting}
            >
              {isSubmitting ? 'Signing in...' : 'Sign in'}
          </Button>
        </form>

        <div>
            {/* or line */} 
          <div className="relative flex items-center">
            <div className="flex-grow border-t border-primary"></div>
              <span className="flex-shrink px-1 text-gray-400 text-sm">Or</span>
            <div className="flex-grow border-t border-primary"></div>
          </div>

          {/* This is the section for login with different platforms */}
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center text-gray-400  mb-4">
            {/* <p className="my-2 text-xs">Login with</p>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              <div className="border-2 border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 transition-colors">
                <Image src='' alt="google" width={30} height={30} />
              </div>
              <div className="border-2 border-gray-400 p-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 transition-colors">
                <Image src='' alt="apple" width={30} height={30} />
              </div>
            </div> */}
            <p className="text-xs font-light my-2">Don&apos;t have an account? <Link className="text-primary underline" href="/auth/user/register">Sign up</Link></p>

            <p className="text-xs font-light space-y-2">Sign in as <Link className="underline text-primary" href="/auth/employee/login">Employee</Link></p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried running this code, the problem is that the program control is not entering the onSubmit function after validation. i don't understand what is the problem, have tried everything to debug this issue
so i have tried to console the issue, but no response.
And i have added type ="submit" , as someother issue said and i am using next.js 14
